# Effect on my application icon when it click by user android

Tags: android, application-icon

How can I add effect for my application icon when it was pressed by user to launch my application. This is not done by theme, I have default android OS and the App which already this implemented was name is **"DU Speed Booster"**

Any suggestion or guidance is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: It's not the app icon, its the app widget

Comment: Widget is not created automatically so I guess is something different. For widget user can only add the widget manually and not by the developer

Comment: Is there any way to detect application icon is clicked and we can replace with another?

Comment: We can add animations on widgets only. For doing that on application icon, there doesn't seem to be a direct way and is not recommended whatsoever.